# Disabling native form validation for a certain button

Tags: html, forms, validation

I have an HTML form in which I use the browser's native validation. However, inside my form I have another button unrelated to the submit that does a different action. When I press that button howver, it fires off the browser's validation, how can I disable that

```
<form>
    <input type="text" required />
    <button>I shouldn't fire validation</button>
    <input type="submit" value="I fire the validation">
</form>
```

Comment: nvm lol see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML 5, button has a default behavior as a submit type. So

```
<button type="button">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

A button by it's own don't fire the submit. You probably have an event setted on it. If you don't, try this other sol

You could use

```
<form>
    <input type="text" required />
    <button type="button">I shouldn't fire validation</button>
    <input type="submit" value="I fire the validation">
</form>
```

It seems weird, but I got if from this example (just in the end of 4.9 section):
http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/forms.html#concept-button

And you can see it working: http://jsfiddle.net/xmhpF/